# Python web scraping using BeautifulSoup, Loop and skip certain URL value

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

So I am using following code to scrape statues from a site.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


f = open('C:\Python27\projects\FL_final.doc','w')

base_url = "http://www.leg.state.fl.us/statutes/index.cfm?App_mode=Display_Statute&URL=0000-0099/00{chapter:02d}/00{chapter:02d}.html"

for chapter in range (1,9):
  url = base_url.format(chapter=chapter)
  r = requests.get(url)
  soup = BeautifulSoup((r.content),"html.parser")
  tableContents = soup.find('div', {'class': 'Chapters' })
  for title in tableContents.find_all ('div', {'class': 'Title' }):
    f.write (title.text)

   for data in tableContents.find_all('div',{'class':'Section' }):
      data = data.text.encode("utf-8","ignore")
      data = "\n\n" + str(data)+ "\n" 
      f.write(data)

f.close()
```

the problem is that certain chapters are missing. For example, there are pages for chapter 1 to chapter 2, then page for chapter 3,4,5 doesn't exist. So when use range (1,9) it gives me errors as it cant pick up chapter 3,4,5 contents, as their (0003/0003, 0004/0004, 0005/0005)url dont exist.

How can I skip missing URLs in my loop and let the program find the next available URL within the range?

here is chapter 1's url: http://www.leg.state.fl.us/statutes/index.cfm?App_mode=Display_Statute&URL=0000-0099/0001/0001.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a `try` for the url request and check that `tableContents is not none` before applying your `find_all` :

```
import requests

f = open('C:\Python27\projects\FL_final.doc','w')

base_url = "http://www.leg.state.fl.us/statutes/index.cfm?App_mode=Display_Statute&URL=0000-0099/00{chapter:02d}/00{chapter:02d}.html"

for chapter in range (1,9):
  url = base_url.format(chapter=chapter)
  try:
    r = requests.get(url)
  except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:    # This is the correct syntax
      print "missing url"
      print e
      sys.exit(1)
  soup = BeautifulSoup((r.content),"html.parser")
  tableContents = soup.find('div', {'class': 'Chapters' })

  if tableContents is not None:
    for title in tableContents.find_all ('div', {'class': 'Title' }):
      f.write (title.text)

    for data in tableContents.find_all('div',{'class':'Section' }):
      data = data.text.encode("utf-8","ignore")
      data = "\n\n" + str(data)+ "\n" 
      print data
      f.write(data)
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply! the code works! Could you explain to me what exactly the try/except. Requestexception function does?

Comment: It's about Handling exceptions (for more, see https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions). But in your case, the issue was related to the `find_all`applied to undefined `tableContents` object (missing chapters).

Answer (score 0):

you can check if tableContents is found, e.g.:

```
    tableContents = soup.find('div', {'class': 'Chapters' })
    if tableContents: 
        for title in tableContents.find_all ('div', {'class': 'Title' }):
            f.write (title.text)
```